# Boot Camp Assistant crashes when partitioning drive (exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Tags: macos, bootcamp, partition, crash

I run Mountain Lion, a fresh install, brand new Macbook Pro. HD: Samsung 840 Pro 512 GB SSD.

When trying to go through Boot Camp Assistant / Setup it works fine until it wants to repartition my drive. It then quits unexpectedly and returns these errors:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000000003c
```

Everything else on this new machine works like a charm. I checked permissions, verified the disk - no issues whatsoever.

I tried running the Assistant as root - it also crashes when partitioning but then in the Terminal i get a

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

[image: Screenshot #1]
[image: Screenshot #2]

Comment: I have not been able to solve the issue, but i was able to find a full workaround. As Boot Camp Assistant crashes AFTER it creates the USB drive with the BC drivers for Windows, i just partitioned the harddisk again myself (in Disk Utility) and then booted up manually and normally with the Windows 7 CD, installed Windows 7 on the target partition and then installed the BC drivers from the USB drive. Everything works perfectly well.

Comment: Great you could find a workaround. I'd suggest that you answer your own question describing the workaround as you've done in the comment and mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Repair Disk on your boot partition. To accomplish this, reboot your Mac into the recovery partition, holding down ⌘R when you see the Apple logo. Select Disk Utility from the menu, then in the First Aid tab click Repair Disk. This may take some time. Partitioning trouble is usually a file system or disk hardware problem; this will solve the former, and a trip to the Apple store is usually needed to address the latter.

Answer (score 1):

For me it crashed when accessing the USB drive.  I reformatted my USB as Mac OS extended via Disk Utility and was able to continue after that.

Comment: For me, this worked but it turned out I then needed to reformat the USB as MS-FAT32.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution that might work for you... Unplug all the external devices that you might have (external disks, flash drives) and then start the bootcamp again.. I just did it and it worked fine for me!!! :)

Comment: Did not work for me back then - i had nothing connected whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having this issue as well when I tried using bootcamp.  I seem to remember that it was due to a fragmented drive that didn't have enough contiguous space to create the partition of the size I was requesting.  From memory, it was a bit of a pain and  I think I ended up partitioning the drive first, then reinstalling OS X on one partition and using Winclone to copy a windows machine directly to the other partition.  There may well be an easier method?

Answer (score -3):

put windows 7 or later version dvd and then you will be able to make partition with BC :)

Comment: this will definetly work dude...